# Make results of a table into variables (increasing dimensions of data) in R (for visualization)

Tags: r, vectorization

I'm not sure how to phrase this question. I have a some data which im trying to get into a different format (maybe even an array) so that i can vectorize it. This isn't very concrete, so here's a simplified example:

I have a file like dt, say:

```
set.seed(1)
time = 1:10
size <- round(runif(10), digits = 1)
count <- round(runif(10)*20)
dt <- data.frame(time,size, count)
dt
     time size count
  1     1  0.3     4
  2     2  0.4     4
  3     3  0.6    14
  4     4  0.9     8
  5     5  0.2    15
  6     6  0.9    10
  7     7  0.9    14
  8     8  0.7    20
  9     9  0.6     8
  10   10  0.1    16
```

and i want to end up with...

```
   time size_0.1 size_0.2 size_0.3 size_0.4 size_0.6 size_0.7 size_0.9
1     1        0        0        4        0        0        0        0
2     2        0        0        0        4        0        0        0
3     3        0        0        0        0       14        0        0
4     4        0        0        0        0        0        0        8
5     5        0       15        0        0        0        0        0
6     6        0        0        0        0        0        0       10
7     7        0        0        0        0        0        0       14
8     8        0        0        0        0        0       20        0
9     9        0        0        0        0        8        0        0
10   10       16        0        0        0        0        0        0
```

which has introduced all the possible results for the size variable as new variables.
Then do a cumulative sum on to get something like this, but really that previous step is the trickiest:

```
   time size_0.1 size_0.2 size_0.3 size_0.4 size_0.6 size_0.7 size_0.9
1     1        0        0        4        0        0        0        0
2     2        0        0        4        4        0        0        0
3     3        0        0        4        4       14        0        0
4     4        0        0        4        4       14        0        8
5     5        0       15        4        4       14        0        8
6     6        0       15        4        4       14        0       18
7     7        0       15        4        4       14        0       32
8     8        0       15        4        4       14       20       32
9     9        0       15        4        4       22       20       32
10   10       16       15        4        4       22       20       32
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `dcast` to create the 'size' columns, and then loop over the 'size' columns (`lapply(...`) and do the `cumsum`.

```
library(reshape2)
dt1 <- dcast(dt, time~paste0('size_', size), value.var='count', fill=0)
dt1[-1] <- lapply(dt1[-1], cumsum)
dt1
#   time size_0.1 size_0.2 size_0.3 size_0.4 size_0.6 size_0.7 size_0.9
#1     1        0        0        4        0        0        0        0
#2     2        0        0        4        4        0        0        0
#3     3        0        0        4        4       14        0        0
#4     4        0        0        4        4       14        0        8
#5     5        0       15        4        4       14        0        8
#6     6        0       15        4        4       14        0       18
#7     7        0       15        4        4       14        0       32
#8     8        0       15        4        4       14       20       32
#9     9        0       15        4        4       22       20       32
#10   10       16       15        4        4       22       20       32
```

Comment: thank you! that did the trick! 
i will probably end up trying to use the spread() function in tidyr as well